# Passar o id de um elemento como parâmetro para uma função?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-eventos

Tenho uma tabela no meu site que está gerando um id automaticamente para cada coluna da tabela.

Coloquei a chamada da função em cada linha.

Como eu faria pra passar o id desse `<td>` por parâmetro na função para que eu consiga identificar qual linha estou clicando?

OBS: Estou usando javascript nativo + angular

Tabela template:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>

                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Tipo Ativo
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Emissor
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Código
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Emissão
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Vencimento
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-click="$ctrl.teste(???)" ng-repeat="dado in $ctrl.dados track by $index">
                            <td>
                                {{dado.campo1}}
                            </td>
                            <td id="dado-{{$index + 1}}">
                                {{dado.tipoAtivo}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{dado.emissor}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{dado.codigo}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {{dado.emissao}}
                            </td>
                            <td id="dado2-{{$index + 1}}">
                                {{dado.vencimento}}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
```

tabela controller:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

class PesquisaAtivosController {
  constructor($state, $scope){
    this.$state = $state;
    this.$scope = $scope;

    this.dados = [
      {
        campo1 : "0",
        tipoAtivo : "c1",
        emissor : "c2",
        codigo : "c3",
        emissao : "c4",
        vencimento : "01/04/2012"
      },
      {
        campo1 : "0",
        tipoAtivo : "TB - Monthly",
        emissor : "Default",
        codigo : "Default",
        emissao : "01/04/2012",
        vencimento : "02/04/2012"
      },
      {
        campo1 : "0",
        tipoAtivo : "c5",
        emissor : "c6",
        codigo : "c7",
        emissao : "c8",
        vencimento : "03/04/2012"
      },
      {
        campo1 : "0",
        tipoAtivo : "c10",
        emissor : "c11",
        codigo : "c12",
        emissao : "c13",
        vencimento : "04/04/2012"
      },
    ];

    localStorage.setItem('dados1','');
    localStorage.setItem('dados2','');
  }

  teste(???){
    var _this = this;
    var dados1 = document.getElementById('???').innerText;
    var dados2 = document.getElementById('???').innerText;

    console.log("ativo:");
    console.log(dados1);
    console.log(dados2);

    window.localStorage.setItem('dados1', dados1);
    window.localStorage.setItem('dados2', dados2);

    _this.$state.go("home.boletoEstoque2");

  }
}

PesquisaAtivosController.$$ngIsClass = true;
PesquisaAtivosController.$inject = ['$state'];

angular.module('app')
  .controller('PesquisaAtivosController', PesquisaAtivosController);
})();
```

Comment: por favor forneça um código exemplo pros leitores entenderem melhor a pergunta

Comment: Qual id vc quer pegar? Tem dois <td> cada qual com um id diferente

Comment: Eu vou precisar pegar os dois

Comment: Não entendo de angular, mas veja se isso funciona: https://jsfiddle.net/hevcczbs/2/

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, esse código (explícito, com js nativo) te ajudará.
Execute, e clique nas tds de resultado. Será exibido no console o Id.

```js
var funcao = function(e){
  console.log(e.target.id);
}

var td = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var i=0; i<td.length; i++){
  td[i].addEventListener('click',funcao)
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>

                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Tipo Ativo
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Emissor
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Código
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Emissão
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Vencimento
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="0">
                                campo1
                            </td>
                            <td id="1">
                                tipoAtivo
                            </td>
                            <td id="2">
                                emissor
                            </td>
                            <td id="3">
                                codigo
                            </td>
                            <td id="4">
                                emissao
                            </td>
                            <td id="5">
                                vencimento
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </table>
```